# Let $f, g$ be entire functions such that $f^2=g^3$. Then there is an entire function $h$ such that $h^3=f$ and $h^2=g$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f, g$ be entire functions such that $f^2=g^3$. Prove that there is an entire function $h$ such that $h^3=f$ and $h^2=g$.

---

My attempt:

If $h=g^{\frac 1 2}$ is a well-defined entire function then everything is trivial. However, if we choose $[0,\infty)$ as a branch cut such that $h$ is analytic in the region $\mathbb C\setminus [0,\infty)$ then there should be an analytic continuation of $h$ on $[0,\infty)$ but I can't see any reason we can do this.

I have also tried to use the power series to express $f$ and $g$, eventually, we have a series of the identity of coefficients of $f^2$ and $g^3$ but this didn't work for me either. Then I got stuck. Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the function
$$
h(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)},&g(z)\not=0\\0,&g(z)=0.\end{cases}
$$
It is clear that when $g(z)=0$, also $g(z)^3=0$ and thus $f(z)^2=0$, meaning that $f(z)=0$ as well. This shows that $h(z)^3=f(z)$ and $h(z)^2=g(z)$ both hold when $g(z)=0$.

Furthermore, note that when $g(z)\not=0$ we have $h(z)^3=f(z)^3/g(z)^3=f(z)^3/f(z)^2=f(z)$, and similarly $h(z)^2=f(z)^2/g(z)^2=g(z)^3/g(z)^2=g(z)$ when $g(z)\not=0$. Thus $h(z)^3=f(z)$ and $h(z)^2=g(z)$ hold everywhere, by this paragraph and the previous.

All that remains is to show that $h(z)$ is entire. Since it is obvious that $h(z)$ is meromorphic, the claim follows by considering the behavior of $f(z)/g(z)$ on a neighborhood of a root of $g(z)$.